# Delphi DBTree Component

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-7

I am seeking a TDBTree component that is very versatile, and i would like to hear some recommendations. I am specifically seeking one that would show a master record and "n" number of Linked table records. (I mean records from various tables). For example, the TDBTree would be hook to master table, and Detail table 1, Additional table, etc.

```
Master Table Record  
  Detail Table 1 Record  
  Detail Table 1 Record  
  Detail Table 1 Record  

  Additional Table  Record  
  Additional Table  Record
```

I am not sure if this is possible or not. This is why i am inquiring. Thanks for any recommendations you may be able to provide.

And example would be

```
Master Checks
 Check Details
 Account Record
 Bank Record
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com) controls. They have something alike what you're looking for. They have both a grid that can show details "in line", and some db-aware trees with many capabilities - IMHO if you're displaying that kind of that their Master-Detail grid is better than any tree, you're going to show different data in each detail.

Comment: i was actually downloading their demo  and came back here to see if there were any responses <smile>. Ill let you know what i discover.

Comment: hmmm, it looks like this "ExpressMasterView" might do the trick. Gonna see if they have a VCL Try begore you buy option to test it. Im stillopen to suggestions though.

Comment: @Shane - Developer's Express has no trial version of any of their products. They offer a money back guarantee instead.

Comment: @Ken, ya, i noticed that. I did install and run their demo though. It gave a pretty good overview of its capabilities. Just not sure if im ready to make the commitment yet. Im still shopping. Thanks

Comment: @Shane - there are no rival to DevExpress grid controls. They are probably not the easiest to use but what I'm pretty sure what you want to do can be done. So, short of writing your own logic to populate a normal VirtualString tree or a JVCL grid (which can be a great thing by itself, since the mentioned components are top notch) DevExpress is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isnt DB aware, but if your open to alternatives then VirtualStringTree is a very good option. I use this tree component displaying most of my DB data to the user - it offers a very flexible and speedy tree/grid for any data. It is very easy to handle DB updating in the many events it provides for you.

Comment: How easy would it be to display (separate) datasources. Data from various link tables. Master, Detail, and additional linked tables all in onve view, with clear separations?

Comment: This thing is fully customizable. You could have the datasources as the root nodes, and then records as sub nodes under them. Once you get used to it, you will find yourself using it for a lot of data display. Check it out: http://www.soft-gems.net